# Use angular JS widget in other popular JS frameworks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

This might sound crazy.

**Description:**
I have few widgets made by using angular, nvd3, bootstrap, etc. These widgets have charts and some other functionality. Each widget has template, angular controller and independent angular service to load data. I can integrate it easily with other angular app.

**Question:**
How can i use these angular widget in other application which is developed by using other JS framework like Ember, React, EXT.js, etc.

Do i need different JS code for each framework i want to integrate? or it could be one piece of JS for any framework?

Does this even possible?
There are two step to this integration. 1. widget is read only 2. widget can talk with widget in other framework.

**Concern:** 
Every framework has different approach to bootstrap application. Most likely i have to write code to link widget for each JS framework. My initial thinking is to have a framework on top of two framework i want to integrate. And I will need similar code for each pair of framework i want to integrate. In my code i have to dynamically load JS frameworks from CDN (if needed for the widget to integrate)

**Real question:**
I am looking for some conceptual guideline or approach that i can take to solve this problem.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Is this for your own projects or for anyone to inject in their own site?

Comment: This is for other teams who want to use my widget in their app